# uWSGI / nGinx performance configuration

Tags: linux, nginx, uwsgi

I have the following:

`net.core.somaxconn = 262144`

`net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 6144`

`net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 6144`

`uWSGI --listen 6144`

nGinx `worker_connections 6144`

But what's the way to calculate these values based on server specs for best performance? Are there any other configuration options I should be looking at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading this blog.

http://modperlbook.org/html/11-1-Setting-the-MaxClients-Directive.html

I will be using this to help me solve the same issues with uWSGI and nginx as well.